# Can't run my project on android emulator while Iphone emulator works fine

Tags: android-studio, react-native, android-emulator, frontend

please can anyone help, I can't run my project on the android emulator, the emulator opens but there is no project app and the bundler doesn't load. While on the iPhone it works fine. Please can anyone help

I have tried re-linking libraries, researching other ways and even posting twice here and on git. But no result, it would be great if i can have a solution. thanks

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-react-native-adapter'.
Project with path ':expo-core' could not be found in project ':expo-react-native-adapter'.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to run project on android emulator but works with Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55944753/unable-to-run-project-on-android-emulator-but-works-with-iphone)

Comment: This is now the fourth time that you ask this same question. This is not how we are supposed to use StackOverflow. (I don't have an answer, unfortunately.)

Comment: Well, to be precise it is the 3rd time, thanks for being a fan and following up with my tracks thought it would be much better if you answered the question then it won't be duplicated. As you might have realized or not it is quite urgent if not I wouldn't bother. you can copy this link to the other questions asked to add to your tracking record if you wish

Comment: It's the fourth, actually. :) And hopefully someone can solve it.

Comment: Actually, after checking, it is the fifth.

Comment: Seems there is an open bug for the last version of expo module, some reports  [HERE](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3942) and [HERE](https://forums.expo.io/t/cant-build-android-project-after-detaching-from-expo-sdk-28-0-0/12239).
Can you try to downgrade it?

Comment: @Legion Thanks for your reply legion I've been waiting for one for a while now. How do I downgrade it and to what version? Sorry I'm new to this